# Do I need anything else other than an SRV record to make it work?

Tags: dns, srv

I'm trying to setup an SRV record to let users connect to a game server.

The server uses the port 27016 UDP and TCP (actually TCP is used just by steam) so I have created two SRV records:

```
_ARKSRV._tcp.join.domain.tld.   SRV domain.tld.
_ARKSRV._udp.join.domain.tld.   SRV domain.tld.
```

But when I try to ping it or use nslookup I get:

```
~$ ping join.domain.tld
ping: cannot resolve join.domain.tld: Unknown host

~$ nslookup -q=SRV _ARKSRV._tcp.join.domain.tld
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find _ARKSRV._tcp.domain.tld: NXDOMAIN
```

I'm wondering if I need to create even an A record to make it work or what.

Answer (score 0):

your zone records:

```
_ARKSRV._tcp.join.domain.tld.   SRV domain.tld.
_ARKSRV._udp.join.domain.tld.   SRV domain.tld.
```

do not match your lookup:

```
~$ nslookup -q=SRV _ARKSRV._tcp.domain.tld
```

Your SRV record also appears to have an incorrect syntax. Part of the reason to use an SRV record is so that you can specify port. Reference [link](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/srv.html)

Comment: sorry actually it was a typo in the question (about the nslookup).  I have used plesk to configure the record and I have specified a port there, so I think the record is correctly created

Comment: might be able to help more with the actual domain record